# how to change the maximum number of fork process by user in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Whenever I login to shell, I get this error

```
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash-3.2$
```

I can't seem to execute any command which uses `fork()`.

I tried `ulimit -u` as it doesn't use fork and it returned `35`. Somehow my max process is set to `35`.

I want to increase that, but I don't know where to make that change.

Answer (score 12):

If you would like to change the limit only for that shell, you could run:

```
sudo ulimit -u 1000
```

If you want to make a more permanent change, you need to edit either `/etc/limits.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.conf` (depending on your linux distro) and add the following lines:

```
username hard nproc 1000
```

Substitute `username` with the actual user name

Instead of username a groupname can also be used if you prefix it with an `@`. If you use `*` it would be the default for all users

Examples:

```
myuser hard nproc 1000
@mygroup hard nproc 3000
*    hard nproc 500
```

Comment: i tried this `sudo ulimit -u 1000` and it again says fork not avaiable. do i need to execute that as root

Comment: Ahh, sudo again requires to fork a process - dang! I guess the only other way is to modify the `limits.conf` by directly logging in as `root`.

Comment: my that file is empty , all lines are comments only

Comment: Yes, then add a newline in that file for the user with the values you're interested.

Comment: i tried that and its not working , do i need to restart somethingto makethatwork

Comment: The user would at least need to logout completely and login again for the changes to take effect. Yes try restarting the box, if that helps.

Comment: `sudo ulimit` should say `sudo: ulimit: command not found`, because like cd, alias, etc. ulimit is a builtin, at least that's what I can confirm on my Archlinux system. So I need to first run su, or sudo su to gain root privilege, and then run ulimit with arguments.

Answer (score 4):

This can be changed in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Look for lines of the form:

```
username hard nproc 25
@groupname hard nproc 100
```

These lines limit `username` user to 25 processes and users in group `groupname` to 100 processes. You **will need root permissions** on the machine though.

Comment: my that file is empty , is there any other system who can limit the process

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned look at `limits.conf`. When you login into Gnome, KDE or any other GUI, you have likely more than 35 processes running already.

Logout from the GUI and switch to a VT with <kbd>Ctl Alt F1</kbd>, for example, and login without a GUI.

Now you should be able to look into `/etc/security/limits.conf`. If it is empty or all commented out, you can look, if there's something in the directory `/etc/security/limits.d`, which has reduced the `ulimit`.

On the console, you should also be able to start additional processes for editing or adjusting `limits.conf` or files in `limits.d`.

Answer (score 0):

Here some ideas :

If your `limits.conf` is empty, `grep -l ulimit /etc/* $HOME/.* 2> /dev/null` to check if someone has set a `ulimit` somewhere, and remove it.

After editing limits.conf, all you have to do is to logout and login again to take effect.

To gain a process, use `exec`. Try for instance `exec sudo su` to become root.

Comment: It should be enough to (re)set the `ulimit`, no need to change configuration (let alone system-wide configuration under `/etc`). And 35 processes should be plenty, something is wrong with the login process of OP.

Comment: @vonbrand - absolutely.  You should post this as the answer with possible things to check. +1

Comment: i had two files , `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc` this was the line ` ulimit -n 100 -u 35 -m 200000 -d 200000 -s 8192 -c 200000 -v unlimited 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to (re)set the ulimit, no need to change configuration (let alone system-wide configuration under `/etc`). And 35 processes should be plenty, something is wrong with the login process of OP.

In a terminal run `ps -au`, that should show all processes running as you, check the list (or post it here) to see if something strange is going on.

Comment: When I look at my process list, I have over 40 processes, started by the gnome environment alone. Not counting the processes I started, like firefox, emacs, bash, ... So, a ulimit of 35 isn't really that much nowadays, if you use a graphical environment.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, Fedora 18 Gnome 3 here; I'm running Firefox, 2 xterms (one with 6 tabs) and an assortment of applets. 17 processes in all.

Comment: Then Fedora is setup a lot leaner than Ubuntu (my system) by default, or you have trimmed your environment before.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, no trimming here.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more possibility that the configuration for "noproc" is not working  while configuring in /etc/security/limits.conf.

There is one more file which overrides your configuration /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf.

```
*          soft    nproc     1024
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

Here * config will override whatever you set in previous config file. So ideally you configure your setting in this file.